# 3D numpy array woes and extracting data

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array, data-science

I have some data concerning the 2020 Australian bush fires I'm trying to work with.

I have some data in numpy arrays: lat (for latitude), lon (for longitude), and time.

The array size of *lat* is: 350 with the shape: (350,)

The array size of *lon* is: 500 with the shape: (500,)

The array size of *time* is: 31 with the shape: (31,) - this makes sense as it's days of the month in Jan 2020.

I have another array, *total_combustion_rate*:

The array size of *total_combustion_rate* is: 5425000 with the shape: (31, 350, 500) - so it's made up of days in the month, *lat* and *lon* values.

I have a final array called *area_array*:

The array size of *area_array* is: 175000 with the shape: (350, 500). It contains the area of each grid square in km2.

I have been asked to work out what percentage of Australia experienced fire during January 2020.

I'm unsure how to go about this problem though.

There are a lot of values in total_combustion_rate that are zero. Getting rid of them should just leave me with entries that mean there is a fire of some description burning in each grid square. I can see that I need to then sum the same lon and lat values in area_array that have a value that isn't zero in total_combustion_rate and that should give me the total area of grid squares that were on fire.

Converting to a percentage should then just be: (total on fire / total area contained in area_array) * 100.

I'm totally lost on how I'd go about doing this though as I get a bit confused with 3D numpy arrays. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming numpy is imported under the name np, and all arrays are numpy arrays.

You have to start by summing `total_combustion_rate` along the time dimension. This way, you will get a 2-D array for which each entry represents an integrated value over time for each location of your dataset.

`total_combustion_rate.sum(axis=0)`

Now, this array is the exact place where you can look for 0 values. The idea is to determine where the non-zero entries are so that you can use their index to probe into `area_array` and get the relevant areas you need. A masked array makes the task extremely easy as it will "hide" these entries you do not want, meaning the ones that sum up to 0.

`np.ma.MaskedArray(area_array, total_combustion_rate.sum(axis=0) == 0)`

When you have the masked array, all you need to do is to compare the sum of the un-masked areas to the sum of all areas. Again, this is achieved effortlessly.

`(np.ma.MaskedArray(area_array, total_combustion_rate.sum(axis=0) == 0).sum()
 / area_array.sum())`

All in one (long) line. :)

Comment: This worked perfectly. Thank you for taking the time to help me.